# How can I change a variable in a child class so that its dependent variables can also be changed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

Does anyone know if it is even possible to change the inherited variables of the parent class by changing a variable in a child class?
Without declaring them in the `__init__` child?

```py
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = "abc"
        self.data_2 = self.data

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
        self.data = "def"

f = Foo()
b = Bar()

print(f.data_2)  # --> abc
print(b.data_2)  # --> abc
```

But I expect to get:

```
print(f.data_2)  # --> abc
print(b.data_2)  # --> def
```

Comment: So, there are no "dependent variables"  - just because a variable was assigned to with the result of some expression that involved another variable does not make them connected in any sense. You need to think about your design more carefully here, so `Foo.__init__` should *take data as an argument*, perhaps with a default of `"abc"`, then in `Bar.__init__`, just call `super().__init__(data="def")`

Comment: Now, another approach is to *provide some interface for manpulating your object's state that maintains this invariant*. e.g. `def set_data(self, data):` which does `self.data = data` and `self.data_2 = data` --although generally in this case you would use a single underscore convetion in the name to singal that the attribute shouldn't be modified directly, self._data = data` etc -- then in your `__init__` (and anywhere else) you use `set_data("def")`, or you can use a `property` in Python as well, which will allow you to use the syntax `self.data = "abc"` instead of `self.set_data("abc")`

Comment: Even resetting `self.data` on the parent class will not change its own `self.data_2`.  You might have some misunderstanding about names and references in Python.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: It's not really clear how to accomplish what you want, as Juanpa and Wim explained. Yet another option might be to make `data_2` a property on `Foo`, like `@property; def data_2(self): return self.data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solves the issue if you don't want to accept `data` as an argument to your init func as someone pointed out above

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = "abc"

    @property
    def data_2(self):
        return self.data

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
        self.data = "def"

f = Foo()
b = Bar()

print(f.data_2)
print(b.data_2)
```

Comment: Thanks , with the help of property I managed to solve my problem!